# Proper typing for sys.stdout and files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to create a method that can handle a string representing a file name, a `Path` object or an already open output stream (`sys.stdout`, `open('...', 'w')`). And I'm trying to properly set the types for `mypy` to check them.

So far I got:

```
import io
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, TextIO, Text


def generate(output: Union[Text, Path, TextIO]) -> None:
    if isinstance(output, io.IOBase):
        output.write("data")
    else:
        if isinstance(output, Text):
            output = Path(output)
        with output.open("w") as output_file:
            output_file.write("data")
```

But `mypy` keeps complaining with

```
Item "TextIO" of "Union[Path, TextIO]" has no attribute "open"
```

AFAIK, TextIO is the proper type to use for a text file, but the `isinstance` check cannot be done against this type. The code structure ensures that at the point of error we cannot have a `TestIO` object, as it had been processed in the previous branch.

How should I tag all the types here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code could be rewritten as follows to isolate `open` in the Path branch, because Mypy understands `isinstance` checks, and call `write` in one place:

```
import io
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union, TextIO, Text
from contextlib import ExitStack


def generate(output: Union[Text, Path, TextIO]) -> None:
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        if isinstance(output, Text):
            output = Path(output)
        if isinstance(output, Path):
            output = stack.enter_context(output.open("w"))
        output.write("data")
```

Comment: Oh! So nice and clean! Yes, having the two equal writes was not a pleasant view, it had some code smell. But I didn't knew about the ExitStack class and I could not process all the inputs in the same way (Text and Path hat to be opened and closed, while the TextIO had to be kept as is). Your advice worked wonders, thanks for the knowledge!